# Given $Ax=b$, if $x^\perp$ is a vector orthogonal to $x$, how can I show that $x^\perp\notin\text{Ker}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, orthogonality

The system is undetermined and consistent and $x$ is a solution of the system.

This is a proof I need as part of a larger problem, but I'm kinda stuck. I don't know if I need to use projections or the idea is simpler and I'm missing something.

Basically, I need to show that $Ax^\perp=\textbf{0}$ is not true (except for $x^\perp=0$). Now, this is clear for $x$ because it is a solution and has to be $Ax=b$. But how can I use the orthogonal relationship between $x$ and $x^\perp$ to prove it for $x^\perp$?

Answer (score 1):

This is false. For example consider a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A$ the projection onto the first coordinate. Take any vector with a non-zero first coordinate and zeroes everywhere else. This vector will satisfy $Ax=b$ for some non-zero $b$ but every vector orthogonal to it is in the kernel of $A$.

Comment: As I imagined, I must've screwed up somewhere. I was actually trying to check if `x+x^{\perp}` was also a solution. I thought this question was a proxy of that one. I think I'll answer a proper question.

Comment: @BananaJump An important theorem in linear algebra is that the column space of a matrix is always orthogonal to its kernel. The kernel will only be non-trivial if it's a projection.

Comment: It’s the **row** space that’s orthogonal to the kernel (null space), not the column space. The column space is a subspace of the codomain, but the kernel is a subspace of the domain. Those two containing spaces might not even have the same dimension. Also, it’s not the case that only projections have nontrivial kernels. Take, for instance, $\small{\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}}$.

Comment: @amd Thanks for the corrections. I often get the row and column spaces confused. I'd also forgotten that nilpotent matrices can have non-trivial kernels too and fail to satisify $P^2=P$ so are not projections. I was confusing it with the canonical projection as one might find in a short exact sequence of vector spaces.